# Capistrano 3 An error occurred while installing passenger

Tags: ruby-on-rails-4, ubuntu-14.04, passenger, capistrano3

I never ran into this problem before and I can't seem to figure out what is going on.

Passenger is installed but when I run

```
cap production deploy
```

I get the following:

An error occurred while installing passenger (5.0.23), and Bundler cannot
continue.
Make sure that `gem install passenger -v '5.0.23'` succeeds before bundling.

My setup is:

2 App servers and 1 DB server. The error is appearing on both the app server. On our staging server, no problem at all.

I just need to be pointed in the right direction. I can't seem to narrow down the problem.

Should I try to uninstall Passenger off the servers and reinstall? (I haven't done this only because of all the configuration I've done)

Comment: I generally install passenger as a system gem, not as an application gem via bundler.

Answer (score 0):

On my production system I installed Passenger/Nginx it via apt-get.  To do that I created a capistrano task (in case I need to rebuild my server).

```
  task :install_passenger do
    on roles(:app) do
      # => https://www.phusionpassenger.com/documentation/Users%20guide%20Nginx.html#install_on_debian_ubuntu
      execute "sudo apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv-keys 561F9B9CAC40B2F7"
      execute "sudo apt-get -y install apt-transport-https ca-certificates"
      execute "echo 'deb https://oss-binaries.phusionpassenger.com/apt/passenger trusty main' | sudo tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list"
      execute "sudo chown root: /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list"
      execute "sudo chmod 600 /etc/apt/sources.list.d/passenger.list"
      execute "sudo apt-get update"
      execute "sudo apt-get -y install nginx-extras passenger"
      execute "sudo service nginx restart"
    end
  end
```

I then added passenger in my gem file in dev group

```
  gem 'passenger' group :development
```